# What am I doing wrong in my SQLAlchemy model and column property?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In my Flask + SQLAlchemy application I have - besider others - these two DB tables/models:

```py
class Client(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "clients"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    client_name = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
    information = Column(String)

class ImageDataSet(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "image_data_sets"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    client_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("clients.id"), nullable=False)

    client = db.column_property(db.select([Client.client_name]).where(Client.id == client_id))
```

So in other words I want to have an attribute `client` in my model `ImageDataSets`, based on the `client_id` from the `Client` model/table. This works, however, when starting the application I get the following warning for my call to `db.column_property`:

> SAWarning: implicitly coercing SELECT object to scalar subquery; please use the .scalar_subquery() method to produce a scalar subquery.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Do as the warning hints at and add `scalar_subquery()` to your query.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Ok sorry for that, I wasn't aware that it would be so easy. If you want to post an answer then I would happily accept it. Or I can answer the solution myself, if you'd prefer that.

Comment: Please feel free to self answer, there is nothing wrong in that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Ilja Everilä's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70427686/what-am-i-doing-wrong-in-my-sqlalchemy-model-and-column-property?noredirect=1#comment124495264_70427686) I solved this by changing the column property to the following:

```py
client = db.column_property(db.select([Client.client_name]).where(Client.id == client_id).scalar_subquery())
```

Now the warning is gone.